# Looking for audio processing library

Tags: open-source, audio, c++, cross-platform, c

I write a program for the development of musical abilities. It is based on the  real-time(low latency) sound processing. It must be cross-platform and ready for porting to a microcontroller.

I use [**PortAudio**](http://portaudio.com/) library for audio I/O, [**Iowa Hills**](http://www.iowahills.com/A7ExampleCodePage.html) functions for Band-pass filtering, [**LAME MP3 Encoder**](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) for mp3 encoding. I also need to have functions for Vibrato effect (*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrato*) and Soft-Knee Dynamic range compression (*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression#Soft_and_hard_knees*). And I have found the necessary functions [in the sources of **Chaotic-DAW**](https://github.com/dliganov/Chaotic-DAW).

That's an example how I use it:

```
#include "daw/effects/rosic_Vibrato.h"
using namespace rosic;
Vibrato Vbr;

Vbr.setAverageDelayTime(1.0); // for the lowest delay

Vbr.setDepth(vibrato_depth);
Vbr.setCycleLength(vibrato_period);
Vbr.setDryWetRatio(vibrato_drywet);
//...

int MyClass::process( const void *input, void *output, 
                  unsigned long, 
                  const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo *, 
                  PaStreamCallbackFlags, 
                  void * )
{
    //...

    for(int i=0; i<BufferSize; i++)
        Vbr.getSampleFrame(&output[i]); // process a sample

    //...
}
```

Chaotic-DAW functions work fine.
The problem is that Chaotic-DAW has a very large and extensive class hierarchy. Therefore, I can not **port my program to microcontroller**, and after adding a Vibrato effect, I even can not port it to Mac OS X.

***So, I'm looking for lite & platform-independent solution for adding a Vibarto effect and Soft-Knee Dynamic range compression (and maybe some similar) to the program.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching and asking questions, I have written my own realization for the vibrato effect: **https://github.com/Bershov/Vibrato-effect**. The code is not hard for understanding and works fine. In fact, the vibrato is a kind of [frequency modulation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation) Its key concepts: variable delay, low-frequency oscillation and intelpolation.